# Fuzzy match for two variables in a dataset

Tags: match, stata, fuzzy-logic

How do I do a fuzzy match (approximately 75% match) between two variables in a Stata dataset?

In my example, I am producing `Match_yes = 1` if the value in `Brand_1` is present in `Brand_2`:

```
**Brand_1    Brand_2    Match_yes**
Samsung     Samsung         1
Microsoft   Apple           0
Apple       Sony            1
Panasonic   Motorola        0
Miumiu                      0
Mottorrola                  1  
LG                          0
```

How do I get the value `Mottorrola` under variable `Brand_1` to produce a `Match_yes = 1`, as it is 80% similar to the value `Motorola` in variable `Brand_2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your toy example:

```
clear

input strL(Brand_1 Brand_2)
Samsung     Samsung     
Microsoft   Apple          
Apple       Sony           
Panasonic   Motorola       
Miumiu                     
Mottorrola                  
LG                          
end
```

Here is a 'hack' using the *community-contributed* command `matchit` to produce the desired output:

```
local obs = _N
generate Cont = 0

forvalues i = 1 / `obs' {
    forvalues j = 1 / `obs' {
        replace Cont = 1 if Brand_1[`i'] == Brand_2[`j'] in `i'

        generate b1 = Brand_1[`i'] in 1
        generate b2 = Brand_2[`j'] in 1
        matchit b1 b2, generate(simscore)
        generate score`i'`j' = simscore
        replace Cont = 1 if score`i'`j'[1] > 0.80 in `i'

        drop b1 b2 simscore
    }
}

drop score*

list

     +------------------------------+
     |    Brand_1    Brand_2   Cont |
     |------------------------------|
  1. |    Samsung    Samsung      1 |
  2. |  Microsoft      Apple      0 |
  3. |      Apple       Sony      1 |
  4. |  Panasonic   Motorola      0 |
  5. |     Miumiu                 0 |
     |------------------------------|
  6. | Mottorrola                 1 |
  7. |         LG                 0 |
     +------------------------------+
```